# Unsplash API - How to obtain search / suggestion words?

Tags: reactjs, api, searchbar

I have a task of making a search bar in React. When you type at least 3 characters in, the suggestions start popping up. Then, after selecting one, the related photos from Unsplash show up on the page.

I've already got two separate components - a search bar that will give suggestions from a hard coded / provided array and a search bar that will show Unsplash photos after typing a word.

But I don't know how to connect them - Do I need an array with Unsplash keywords? But how do I obtain it? I don't think I should be preloading all millions of photos first, do I?

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: Maybe there is an API like `https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?query=your_search_text`. Check [this](https://unsplash.com/developers) and [this](https://unsplash.com/documentation#search-photos)

Answer (score 0):

In documentation of the project theres no word about returning suggestions, so I think they don't support this.
If you ask how is it working on production - api is returning an object with 5 suggestions related to sent query. You can check this in "Network" tab when you type something into the searchbar on their website, just paste the link they fetch into your browser.
Does it answer your question?